# How does BindingList<T> know the selected Item?

Tags: c#, binding, listbox

When you use a BindingList as Binding for lets say a ListBox

```
listBox.DataSource = myBindingList;
```

and bind some labels to the same source:

```
labelName.DataBindings.Add("Text",
                           myBindingList,
                           "Name",
                           false,
                           DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The value of the labels change when the `SelectedItem` of my listBox is changed.

Why do the values of my labels always refer the currently selected item?

How do they know, by just giving them the `BindingList` as source, which item in the List is the selected one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When doing data-binding in windows-forms, the UI has access to a `BindingContext` and a `CurrencyManager`. The `BindingContext` comes (ultimately) from the parent form, and the `CurrencyManager` is obtained *from* the `BindingContext` via the data source reference. So: if two controls on the same form are given the same data-source, then *assuming they use the normal binding patterns*, they will get the same `CurrencyManager`. It is the `CurrencyManager` that tracks the selected item.

Note: it *is possible* to split the `BindingContext` on a per-control basis; but the *default* is for it to be inherited - thus all controls on the same form will share a `BindingContext`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to change the selected item manually?

Comment: @Pulle sure; get hold of the currency manager (`var cm = (CurrencyManager)control.BindingContext[dataSource];`) and change the `.Position`